# Placing DIV on the right side of form

Tags: html, css

I have a div in a form and i want to place the div on the right side of the form and the div must be fixed on the right side with the button. I don't know if this can be done but how can i get this done.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
         <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--i want to move this div to the right side of the form and fixed-->
   <div  style="background-color:white" class="move-right" id="move-right">
      <legend style="text-align: center" >Heading <span></span></legend>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn ">Save</button>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd begin trying with `float:right` or `position:absolute;right:0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  the content of the right should **not overlap** the other content you need:

*.move-right { float:right; }* in the css.
And reorder the html code to place the floating element above the others:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
       <div  style="background-color:white" class="move-right" id="move-
right">
          <legend style="text-align: center" >Heading <span></span></le zgend>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
             <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" 
placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn ">Save</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

otherwise, if the contents **can overlap**:

use the *.move-right { position: absolute; right: 0px; }* and *.form-horizontal { position: relative; }* css code.